# Лучшая СУБД для хранения небольших таблиц в одном файле-контейнере

Tags: python, база-данных, ms-access

У меня есть небольшая реляционная база данных, реализованная в MS Access, имеющая 7-8 небольших таблиц (количество записей в самой большой таблице <1000). В настоящее время мне нужно построить новый проект на основе этой старой реализации БД, и я хочу найти правильное решение: какую БД лучше всего использовать.

Главным недостатком MS Access является его древний язык VBA и модули, хранящиеся вместе с данными БД в одном файле без возможности их извлечения и управления ими.

С другой стороны, я считаю, что решение хранить все данные в одном файле (как это делается в MS Access - все данные БД содержатся в одном файле .accdb) – это очень удобно.

Итак, вот список требований к такой новой БД:

1. Хранить таблицы в одном файле-контейнере, который можно передать любому
   человек, имеющий Windows или Linux. Этот человек должен быть в состоянии
   просмотреть этот файл, используя только легкодоступное предустановленное
   програмное обеспечение.
2. В среде IDE этой БД должны быть все основные дружественные интерфейсы и функции, которые
   можно найти в MS Access, а именно:

   - Управление таблицами БД: создание, удаление, изменение
   - Визуальный инструмент «tables relationship»
   - Браузер / редактор таблиц с возможностью проверки ограничений отношений
   - Построение и хранение SQL-запросов
   - Дополнительно: дизайнер форм GUI
3. Языки программирования:

   - Python
   - Опционально: C ++
   - Опционально: Perl

Какая база данных соответсвует моим требованиям больше всего?

Comment: Sorry, i don`t good speak English, but sqlite3 - this is seems to be what you're most likely looking for.

Comment: Я нормально понимаю русский, я же написал в конце. Просто не хотел переводить готовый вопрос. 
По поводу sqlite - я ищу что-то похожее на sqlite, но имеющее больше тулов, типа как я описал, table relationship, что есть в MS Access

Comment: Ваш вопрос будет закрыт, так как на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: @MarianD  Я уже выбрал решение - это Firebird, так что можете спокойно закрывать

Comment: @RedSoft, у меня нет такого права, чтобы я мог сам закрыть его. Но посмотрите, многие люди здесь потому, что они не владеют английским языком.

Comment: @MarianD По вашей просьбе перевёл на русский

Comment: @RedSoft, спасибо вам. Вы даже можете написать ответ на ваш собственный вопрос и он может быть полезным для других людей (и вы можете получить за него баллы).

Comment: @MarianD Так куда же мне писать ответ, если вы закрыли мой вопрос, хотя я его не поленился и таки перевёл!

Comment: @RedSoft, ваш вопрос будет переоткрыт, я уже голосовал за его переоткрытые. Хорошо, что вы здесь об этом написали.

Comment: @RedSoft переоткрыли)

Answer (score 1):

Вынесу ответ [RedSoft](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/389613/redsoft) из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1128184/%d0%9b%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%a1%d0%a3%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5#comment1950781_1128184)

> Я уже выбрал решение - это Firebird

PS: к сожалению, автор не дал более развернутого ответа

Comment: Я сейчас строю проект на Firebird + QtPy + Fdb для Python 
Когда я буду иметь перед собой полную картину, тогда и отпишусь сюда в виде выводов и т.п.